# How to configure sqlite to be universal across all versions of windows for a desktop bridge winforms app?

Tags: winforms, windows-10-universal, desktop-bridge

I have a win forms app that targets .net 4.6.1, which allows the user to choose the database type they prefer on login. Deploying to appx via desktop bridge breaks the SQLite function. I want as little fragmentation as possible, as I'm the only person working on my app. After reading that windows 10 has its own managed version of SQLite, the question now becomes, what is the best practice approach that allows all windows version users to use sqlite without splitting the app into multiple versions?

Comment: What's  the current version of SQLite you are using?

Comment: Have you read this updated article for incorporating SQLite into UWP apps? - https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases